# Prove that if $a+b+c=1$ then $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\le\frac{9\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, examples-counterexamples, radicals, fractions

Let $a,b,c>0$,and such $a+b+c=1$,prove or disprove
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+a^2}}\le\dfrac{9\sqrt{2}}{2}\tag{1}$$

My try:since
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\ge\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(a+b)$$
it suffices to prove that 
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{a+b}\le\dfrac{9}{2}$$
But since Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$2\sum_{cyc}(a+b)\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{a+b}\ge 9$$
or
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{a+b}\ge \dfrac{9}{2}$$
so this try can't works.so How to prove $(1)$

Comment: In fact, we have a sort of opposite: $$ \sum_{a,b,c\text{ : cyc}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} > 4 + \sqrt{2} $$ with the equality holds as one of $a, b, c$ tends to $0^+$ and the others tend to $1/2$.

Comment: What is the definition of cyc? I can imagine it to mean cycle or cyclic, cycling through a certain set of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's wrong. Try $a=b\rightarrow0^+$

Comment: Thanks,This inequality $LHS\ge\dfrac{9\sqrt{2}}{2}$?

Comment: It's also wrong. Try $a=b\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}$ and $c\rightarrow0^+$.

Comment: Thanks,I have understand,can you help this new inequality,maybe is right,and it's interesting

Answer (score 4):

It is false. Try $a=\frac{9}{10},\, b=c=\frac{1}{20}$.

Comment: Nice,example +1